# font awsome does not work when page is in a different folder

Tags: fonts, path

This maybe trivial, but it has me puzzled.
I have a basic font awsome sample; it works fine when the css and font folders are at the same folder level as the page.html, but when I move the page.html to a directory called "mySubDir", then the fonts do not load.
I've modified the css reference as shown below.
I also tried changing the path to the font in the font-awesome.min.css file (although it should not be needed since relative paths in css are relative to the css) but it did not make any difference.
Any ideas?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="../mySubDir/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you move your html file, then the relative path to your css will change. The "../" part of the file path says, go one folder up from where this html file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Firefox does not permit to view a file at the parent level unless you change the firefox settings.